# Word for "realizing something after an explanation"

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, if I wrote "word" with poor handwriting, and you couldn't tell what it was, but then I told you that it said "word", and you replied, "Ah, I see how it could say word." Is there a word describing this type of after-the-fact realization?

Comment: You might check synonyms of *eureka* or *eureka moment*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the informal definition of “click” (from OED):

> click
>
> (verb, informal):
>
> Become suddenly clear or understandable.
>
> ‘I wasn't used to such good treatment, then it clicked: we were wearing suits’

Answer (score 0):

If someone 'sees' something after an explanation it is '**enlightenment'**.

> The action of bringing someone to a state of greater knowledge, understanding, or insight; the state of being enlightened in this way. Also: an instance of this.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/62448?redirectedFrom=enlightenment#eid)

> 1990   Shareware Mag. Nov.–Dec. 9/1   This column is a place to network with other users for mutual enlightenment

Answer (score -1):

**Elucidate** (verb) or **elucidation** (noun). Both require explanation to bring about a sense of greater learning.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elucidate) on elucidate:

> (transitive) : to make lucid especially by explanation or analysis
>
> (intransitive) : to give a clarifying explanation

Here's two examples based on what you wrote:

> At first I didn't understand the inscription, but you elucidated it for me.
>
> You provided elucidation to me, and for that I thank you.

Comment: That’s the word for explaining, not for the realization that comes after the elucidation.

Comment: The thing is made lucid in your understanding by explanation or analysis. How is that different than realization?

Comment: OP is asking for something more like “ah ha moment” imho

Comment: Ahh. Okay. Then I think *eureka* is better than *enlightenment* or my answer, since both are bound up in the process rather than the realization itself.

Comment: If I don’t understand, you elucidate, I then realize.

Comment: Yes, eureka is much better, but to nit pick, it doesn’t capture the idea of “after explanation.” You can have a eureka moment all by yourself dropping lead rings into the tub

Comment: The very act of elucidating (or enlightening) means I *have* realized it. After all, if your explanation was a failure, nothing was elucidated, and the term would not apply. They don't occur sequentially; realization (being made lucid) is a precondition for elucidation.